# Обработка ошибок в классе

Tags: android

Есть отдельный класс, не зависящий от `Activity`:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
  try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      InputStream content = entity.getContent();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
      }
    } else {

      Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
    }
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Если файл не получилось загрузить - приложение просто закрывается с ошибкой. Как обработать эту ошибку?

Comment: с каким именно исключением падает приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создать интерфейс с ивентами (один из которых как раз и ваша ошибка)

   **void onError(String msg, ...);**
2. Когда вызываете запрос на сервер передайте делигат на этот интерфейс в конструктор
3. Когда происходит ошибка, делегируйте сообщение делегату
4. В Activity (думаю что его можно сделать делегатом), обработайте данную ошибку, обычным диалогом или Toast

Answer (score 1):

Оборачивать исключение в какое-то своё осмысленное и пробрасывать наверх, дабы вызывающая сторона сама решала, что с ним делать.